# Name of dominant dinosaur

Tags: species

I seem to remember reading some time ago about a dinosaur appearing very prominently in the fossil record, with continent-wise distribution. The layer is known specifically for having so many fossils of this dinosaur and might be named as such. Terms "cow-sized", "vegetarian", and "near to extinction event" come to mind. Does this ring a bell?

My memory might be so faulty that it could be an early amphibian, reptile or even mammal!

Answer (score 3):

The closest example I can think of is [*Lystrosaurus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lystrosaurus#Dominance_of_the_Early_Triassic), which was one of the most common animals in the early Triassic period. It was distributed across many modern continents, and was roughly the size of a pig or cow, depending on the species. *Lystrosaurus* was not a dinosaur, despite its name.

[image]

Excerpt from the Wikipedia page (emphasis mine):

> *Lystrosaurus* is notable for dominating southern Pangaea during the Early Triassic for millions of years. At least one unidentified species of this genus survived the end-Permian mass extinction and, in the absence of predators and of herbivorous competitors, went on to thrive and re-radiate into a number of species within the genus, becoming the most common group of terrestrial vertebrates during the Early Triassic; for a while **95% of land vertebrates were *Lystrosaurus***. This is the only time that a single species or genus of land animal dominated the Earth to such a degree

Comment: Note that Lystrosaurus was not a dinosaur; it was a [dicynodont therapsid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicynodont).  However, it may well be the answer to the question anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for. For some reason, I can't mark this answer as correct, doesn't give me the option. Maybe a moderator can do it?